# Magento 2: Definition of function getOptionsCollection

Tags: magento2, extend

I'm trying to extend a function getOption() of Bundle Class(Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php) in my own Class
using following code

```
protected $_ProductBundle;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
array $data = [],
\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle $ProductBundle,
)
{
        $this->_ProductBundle = $ProductBundle;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

and then I declared this getOptions function in the same class

```
public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->_ProductBundle->getOptions();
    }
```

I'm getting following error when I call above function from my phtml file

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getOptionsCollection()
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\app\code\Vendor_Name\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductBundleNew.php
>   on line 82

Above function getOptionsCollection() is coming from getOptions function from Bundle.php

```
public function getOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->options) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
            $typeInstance->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);

            $optionCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsCollection($product);

            $selectionCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection(
                $typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );

            $this->options = $optionCollection->appendSelections(
                $selectionCollection,
                false,
                $this->catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck()
            );
        }

        return $this->options;
    }
```

I'm not able to get the definition of getOptionsCollection.
Is this function declared somewhere else? do I have to extend some other class to call this function?

Comment: after searching through Magento modules, getOptionsCollection function comes from **Type.php** `Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type.php`